# How properly convert the apache config to nginx? Given $request_filename

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

In the /projects/ subfolder I have an htaccess with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index\.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index\.html !-f
RewriteRule . /template/template-project.php [L]
```

It allows to redirect if a subfolder in /projects/ does not contain indexed php or html.

Okay, the online converter gave me this result:

```
location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /template/template-project.php break;
  }
}
```

I see that this is an incomplete config, and does not work at all. I've tried different combinations, but in many cases I get a 403 error.

What should this type of config even look like?

Answer (score 1):

got the answer:

```
    location /projects {
        index index.html index.php /template/template-project.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /template/template-project.php?$query_string;
    }
```